# Collection View Layout Problems

Tags: xamarin.ios, uicollectionview

I'm working with `CollectionViews` and currently have the problem that everytime I implement a `UICollectionViewFlowLayout` my original layout gets "destroyed". If I dont implement a FlowLayout, my `CollectionView` is just one row that has the length of all items in it and everything works fine. But the elements in the `CollectionView` are spaced really far from another. To use a smaller spacing I need to implement the FlowLayout, but as I do that, my `CollectionView` uses a grid layout AND each element in it shrinks down to like 20x20 pixels.

Where do I tell the FlowLayout to use just one row and how can I lower the spacing between elements  in a `CollectionView`? I saw something like

```
ItemsLayout = new LinearItemsLayout(ItemsLayoutOrientation.Vertical)
    {
        ItemSpacing = 20
    }
```

but I dont know where to put that code. Can someone help me? :/

Thats what my current FlowLayout looks like:

```
    public class TestFlowLayout : UICollectionViewFlowLayout
{
    public TestFlowLayout()
    {
    }

    public override bool ShouldInvalidateLayoutForBoundsChange(CGRect newBounds)
    {
        return true;
    }

    public override UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes LayoutAttributesForItem(NSIndexPath indexPath)
    {
        return base.LayoutAttributesForItem(indexPath);
    }

    public override UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes[] LayoutAttributesForElementsInRect(CGRect rect)
    {
        return base.LayoutAttributesForElementsInRect(rect);
    }

    public override void PrepareLayout()
    {
        base.PrepareLayout();
    }

    public override void InvalidateLayout()
    {
        base.InvalidateLayout();
    }
}
```

I also tried something like this in my `ViewDidLoad`:

```
CollectionView.CollectionViewLayout = new TestFlowLayout
        {
            MinimumLineSpacing = 0,
            MinimumInteritemSpacing = 0,
            SectionInset = new UIEdgeInsets(0, 0, 0, 0),
            ScrollDirection = UICollectionViewScrollDirection.Horizontal
        };
```

but I still get a grid layout instead of a linear one.

I also added

```
public override nint NumberOfSections(UICollectionView collectionView)
    {
        return 1;
    }
```

in my UICollectionViewDataSource. But nothing works..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Cause :** If **UICollectionView** has space for more than one Cell in one direction, it's going to let the Cell fill it. For example, we set the sliding direction of UICollectionView to be horizontal. At this point, if the height of the Cell is insufficient, the following situation may occur:

[image]

**Solution:**

Generally speaking, to display a single row (single column), you only need to make the height of the Cell greater than 1/2 of the height of UICollectionView. Then a row is not enough to put down two cells, so the single-row arrangement will naturally appear:

[image]

So in your case you just need to set the Frame of **UICollectionView** .

Comment: This was the solution. Nice :) I added

 CollectionView.CollectionViewLayout = new TestFlowLayout
        {
            MinimumLineSpacing = -30,
            MinimumInteritemSpacing = 0,
            SectionInset = new UIEdgeInsets(0, 0, 0, 0),
            ScrollDirection = UICollectionViewScrollDirection.Horizontal,
            ItemSize = new CGSize(125,125)
        };

and it worked. For the spacing I had to make the minimum line spacing negative though..